# How do I open more than one excel workbook from within matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, export-to-excel

In the code below I open an excel workbook from within MATLAB:

```
    wbk=1;fName = fullfile(pwd, 'test1');
    %# create Excel COM Server
    Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
    Excel.Visible = true;
    %# delete existing file
    if exist(fName, 'file'), delete(fName); end
    %# create new XLS file
    wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
    wsheet=1;
    wb.Sheets.Item(wsheet).Activate();
    % Get Worksheets object
    ws = wb.Sheets;
    ...
```

The code goes on to fill up the workbook sheets with calculations.  My question is how do I open up another workbook?  I want to send some of the matlab calculation output to one of the workbooks and some of the output to another one.

(By the way, the above code largely taken from other related posts in this forum.  Many thanks to those who posted it.)

Answer (score 0):

Just call Add() again.

```
wb2 = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
ws2 = wb2.Sheets;
```

Now you have two workbooks open in that session. Split the output between the two books by calling methods on wb or wb2, respectively.